# How do I reverse this basic encrypt?

Tags: java, string, character

```
public static String basicEncrypt(String s) {
    String toReturn = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
        toReturn += (int)s.charAt(j);
    }
    //System.out.println("Encrypt: " + toReturn);
    return toReturn;    
}
```

Is there any way to reverse this to find the original string? Much appreciated.

Comment: Cast it back to a character.

Comment: Do you only use US ASCII?

Comment: This is everything that's used to generate the encrypted String yes.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the String? Is it just basic characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, [, ])?

Comment: Isn't that a hash? which cannot be reversed

Comment: With US ascii and no line feeds, it's doable, otherwise much trickier.

Comment: It generates this: 10710510111497110, and this is a 6 letter word.

Comment: Yeah how did you reverse it? Could you please tell me?

Comment: US ascii, no line feed; Anything starting with 1 (or 2 if you restrict some more low number control characters and want to go to 255) is a 3 digit number, anything else a 2 digit number, just lookup in the ascii table. 107, 105, 101, 114, 97, 110.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, I get it. This would be possible with a few methods right?

Comment: @user1848712 Yes, as I type I see implementations of similar approaches appearing below in the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that you only use ASCII characters (32-255 codes) the algorithm is simple:

1. Take the first character of input
2. If it's `1` or `2` - take and cut off next two digits and convert to character
3. If it's any other character - take and cut off next digit and convert to character
4. Go to 1. if some input left

Here is a quick'n'dirty Scala implementation:

```
def decrypt(s: String): String = s.headOption match {
    case None => ""
    case Some('1') | Some('2') => s.substring(0, 3).toInt.toChar + decrypt(s.substring(3))
    case Some(_) => s.substring(0, 2).toInt.toChar + decrypt(s.substring(2))
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if taken in account that your original string consists of characters between and including  (32) and unicode charcode 299, see http://www.asciitable.com/

```
Psuedo code
ret=<empty string>
while not end of string
  n=next number from string
  if n<3 charcode= n + next 2 numbers
  else
     charcode=n + next number
  ret=ret + character(charcode)
end while
```

Charcodes under space (newlines and carriage returns)and above 299 will thwart this algorithm. This algorithm can be fixed to include characters up to charcode 319.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String basicDecrypt(String s) {
    String result = "";
    String buffer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        buffer += s.charAt(i);
        if ((buffer.charAt(0) == '1' && buffer.length() == 3) || (buffer.charAt(0) != '1' && buffer.length() == 2)) {
            result += (char) Integer.parseInt(buffer);
            buffer = "";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is a very basic decryption method. It will only work for `[A-Za-z0-9]+` US ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'll see what I can do from here now I know how the conversion works.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, another couple of versions; Java, US-ASCII only, chars 0x14-0xc7;

```
public static String basicDecrypt(String input)
{
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(1..|[2-9].)").matcher(input);
    while(matcher.find())
        output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
    return output.toString();
}
```

For 0x1e-0xff, replace the regex with `"([12]..|[3-9].)"`

...and a somewhat briefer Linq'y C# version.

```
private static string BasicDecrypt(string input)
{
    return new string(Regex.Matches(input, "(1..|[2-9].)").Cast<Match>()
                           .Select(x => (char) Int32.Parse(x.Value)).ToArray());
}
```